# Persisting the order of a meteor publish function on the client

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a Meteor collection with a field that I do not want to publish to the client. However, I would like to have the collection sorted by this field. Since the sort order from the server doesn't persist on the client, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of research, I've found a solution. I do the sort on the server and transform the documents to include an 'order' field before publishing.

On the Server:

```
Meteor.publish('usersOrderedByPrivateField', function () {
   var cursor = Meteor.users.find({}, {sort: {privateField: 1});
   var order = 0;
   var self = this;
   cursor.fetch().forEach(function (doc) {
       doc.order = order++;
       delete doc.privateField;
       self.added("users", doc._id, doc);
   });
   this.ready();
}
```

And on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('usersWithPrivateFieldOrdering');
Meteor.users.find({},{sort:order:1});
```

Please add an answer or comment if there's a better way of accomplishing this.